# \newline causing TeX capacity exceeded error

Tags: macros, errors

I'm rigging up some code so that I get the references cited on a slide displayed directly in the `footline` of my beamer presentation, and I've run into an error that mystifies me. The code I have (which works) is this:

```
\def\framerefs{}
\def\interframerefs{}
\def\clearframerefs{\gdef\framerefs{}\gdef\interframerefs{}}

\def\cite#1{\xdef\framerefs{\framerefs\interframerefs#1}\gdef\interframerefs{~}}
\defbeamertemplate{footline}{footline refs}{
    \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,dp=1ex]{refs in foot}%
        \framerefs
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
    \clearframerefs
}
\setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\normalsize}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[footline refs]
```

But if I want each reference on a separate line, and change `\cite` to be:

```
\def\cite#1{\xdef\framerefs{\framerefs\interframerefs#1}\gdef\interframerefs{\\}}
```

The compilation fails with a capacity exceeded error:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000].
<argument> ...le }\framesubtitle }\framesubtitle }
                                                  \framesubtitle }\framesubt...
```

I find it a bit odd that having a space be the separator works fine but newlines explode (same thing happens with `\newline`). Does someone know what's wrong (or a better way to do the newline-separated list thing I want to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\xdef\framerefs{\framerefs\interframerefs#1}
```

is an accident waiting to happen.

Try

```
 \protected@xdef\framerefs{\framerefs\interframerefs#1}
```

or safer

```
 \g@addto@macro\framerefs{\interframerefs#1}
```

(Untested as no runnable example supplied)

Comment: `\protected@xdef` did the trick. `\def\cite#1{\g@addto@macro\framerefs{\interframerefs#1}\gdef\interframerefs{\\}}` seems to have different semantics, as with that I get a `\newline` before the first cite (which LaTeX complains about: "There's no line here to end."). Thanks for the help!